# I cannot Reinstall linux without being infected

Tags: partitioning, security, malware

I have tried for a couple times now to reinstall any version of linux to a PC on my network.

I got hacked about 6 months ago by someone on a game, and I haven't been able to comfortably reinstall linux since.

Maybe i'm paranoid, but should my tmp file be full when I go to boot up the system? also, last time I tried to run it in a VM, it kept partitioning the hard drive into other partitions.

Comment: That is normal if you don't have enough storage. But normally /tmp should be cleared during the boot process

Comment: Get access to another computer that you are sure is not infected, download the Ubuntu ISO on that computer and burn it to a DVD (yes, use an actual DVD that is a read-only medium rather than a USB stick). If you don't have a DVD drive, find someone who has an external DVD drive and borrow that drive. Reinstall Ubuntu on your computer booting from that DVD. In this way, there's no possibility to get infected.

Comment: I suggest you read https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic as I see nothing on-topic for this site. You don't mention any specific OS/release, nor any clues as to what installer you're asking about with installation (*Ubuntu has five installers, with some better for some circumstances than others*) and mention only Linux which is covered by SE *Unix & Linux* and not this site. Your problem seems to be *user* or *procedure* specific without any details.

Comment: That's the thing, any ubuntu, kali, parrot, but i put around 100gigs on the thing and the space just gets used up pretty quickly. Also happened on 22.3 and 23.3